# Computational complexity of simple algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

I have simple algorithm, something like

```
h = SHA1(message)
r = a^b mod p
r = h * r mod p
l = Str1 || Str2
if ( l == r)
  return success
else
  return false
```

Now I want to compute its complexity, but I didn't konw how to do it. I don't know e.g. how the multiplication is done, so I don't understand how to do it. Assume worst case O(n^2) or best case or average case? Maybe I must look on it from other side?

Additionaly the numbers are keep as a byte arrays.

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Comment: Its just whatever complexity of SHA1 is, everything else is a constant factor.

Comment: What is `n`? Message length?

Comment: Why it is constant factor, e.g r = a^b mod p, a and b are 256 bits(32 bytes) long, so I don't think that complexity of it is O(1)?

Comment: n is the length of numbers and equals to 256 bits.

Comment: You measure complexity w.r.t a variable. If a and b are 256 bits, a^b is doable in O(1).

Comment: You need to precisely define the size of the input to your algorithm before you can compute the complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know the complexity of this algorithm, you just have to add the complexitys of the operations you use and sum it up.

- `sha1(message)` has a complexity depending on the length `m` of the message, so lets say poly(m), since I dont know the complexity of sha1.
- `ab mod p` can be done in `O(log b)` multiplications.
- `h * r mod p` is exactly one multiplication
- `Str1 || Str2` Is this bitwise or? If yes it will take `O(s)` where `s` is the length of `Str1`
- `l == r` will take as much comparisons as the length of the byte array is. This will also be `s`.

When numbers are realy big. The can not multiplicated in one processor step, so complexity of one multiplications will be in `O(log p)`, since `log p` is the length of the numbers.

All together you get `O(poly(m) + log(b) ⋅ log(p) + s)`.

**Notice**: If the length of the numbers (`log(b)` and `log(p)`) will never change, this part will be constant. This also holds for `s`.

You said the numbers are 256 Bit long, so the complexity is only `O(poly(m))`, which is the complexity of the Sha1-algorithm.

**Notice**: If you have an algorithm with any complexity, an you only use input of a fixed length, the complexity will always be constany. Complexity is a tool to see how the runtime will expand if the input is growing. If it is not growing, the runtime will also not.
If your input has always a fixed length, than you are more interested in the performance of the implementation of an algorithm.